# Android Help: changing focus of buttons with delay and performing click

Tags: android

I just started learning Android programming. I am making an app which can be controlled from an external device. I need 4 buttons, their focus changes periodically with a delay of 2s. when I press the sensor, the `performclick()` will be done. I don't know how to implement it. I use a switch case statement to get sensor data. If required case is happened, I need to do perform click on that button. Till that case, the focus should be cyclically change.

eg: Button 1 =>Button 2 =>Button 3 =>Button 4 =>Button 1 (focus change with 2s delay)

if case condition is true, `button.performclick` on current focused button.

Can any one say a structure or program code? I searched a lot but I can't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a handler with postDelayed() method. This method take a class that implement the runnable interface.

In this class, you just change the current button focus, and call again the postDelayed() method, with your delay (2000).

Code :

In your activity :

```
private Handler handler;
private static final int DELAY = 2000;

onCreate()
{
 this.handler = new Handler();
 this.handler.postDelayed(ChangeFocusClass, DELAY);
}
```

The runnable class (inner class) :

```
public class ChangeFocusClass implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        nextButton.requestFocus(); // You need to know which button you have to set focused
        handler.postDelayed(ChangeFocusClass, DELAY);
    }

}
```

This is not complete, but give you a global idea.

Comment: can you post an example code? should i write it under oncreate() ? or under main class?

Comment: thank you. can you pls tell me how to focus on definit button? should i just use nextfocusright? or specify button name.requestfocus ? how to loop it to move from one button to another?

Comment: You can use an arraylist of buttons, populate that list and keep in mind the current index of the focused button. ArrayList and currentIndex in the activity. Then, currentIndex++; buttonList.get(currentIndex).requestFocus();

Comment: i am getting an error that, currentfocusclass cannot beresolved for the above code..

Comment: hi , i need the sample program of a simple socket server on android to send data to a client running on ELAN home automation controller. i have a button in my app, when i click it, i need to send "11" to the client running on ELAN. i saw a lot of program to listen the clients here.please help